Plumbing from washing machine
Okay, I need to plumb some water into my house in order to have running water. (I have to haul water.) I have run a hose into the cold water tap of the washing machine as I need an inside connection due to freezing weather. I then use a pump. I am getting running water into the house, both hot and cold, albeit low pressure, but my question is, will my hot water tank refill with this connection? I tried connecting the pumped water to both taps but then got only cold water.

It should refill, but your connection might be wrong, the cold water inlet is at the bottom, while the hot water outlet is at the top of the tank

I assume this is some sort of temporary post-disaster arrangement where your normal water supply has been damaged?

DIY, it's connected from the holding tank, pumped through the cold water tap of the washer, not directly to the hot water tank. The hot water tank is in the crawlspace, the washer is on the main floor.

Ecnerwal, it is temporary post disaster but unfortunately will be until spring. I haven't the funds or the tools to get the water supply from my well going until then.

In most normal household plumbing systems putting the cold water supply in at any point of the cold water piping should work, since pipes (without check valves) don't care about direction of flow in them.
So if you supply cold water to the cold water hookup at the washing machine (converting it from an outlet to an inlet) and have, we hope, shut off the main supply valve leading to the pipe that no longer brings water to your house (I presume) then yes, the water heater will refill. Indeed, unless the water heater is in an odd position and not plumbed to code, the fact that you get hot water is a clear sign that the cold water is being supplied to it.
A better place to hook up your temporary supply would a hose bib or boiler drain valve (so called, not the one on your actual boiler, if any) on the house side of the main shutoff valve for the water supply, so that the diameter of the pipes is arranged in the usual way for best flow, rather than possibly running a long way on small pipe from the washer outlet back to larger pipes, but trying to feed the whole house through that small pipe. Having a valve in that location is fairly standard, as it allows testing that the supply is working correctly without other factors getting in the way, and also facilitates draining the system in case of possible freezing (such as a long power outage in cold weather.)
However, most likely the hose itself is the limiting factor in your flow/pressure being low.
